# ng-model not getting default value checkbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/2644/

Why is my default value of 'checked' in each of my filters not getting set in the checkbox on page load?

I was using the batarang to debug it and it looks like the model is getting updated when i click the checkbox, but the default value of 'checked' being true doesn't look like its getting applied.

it does seem to work if i use ng-checked="filter.checked" but i'm not sure why.

JavaScript:

```
$scope.filtersList = [
    {"name":"type","checked":"true","label":"Source(s)","CSSClasses":"",
     "values":[
         {"key":"Online News","value":1,"parent":"false","children":[],"checked":"true"},
         {"key":"Twitter","value":15,"parent":"false","children":[],"checked":"true"}]
    },
```

HTML:

```
<div class="filter-listing" ng-controller="sidebar">
        <ul class="filterSection" ng-repeat="filter in filtersList">
        <li class="clearfix">
            <span class="pull-left">
                <a class="pull-left twistdown filterToggle"
                    href="#" title="Expand" data-toggle="collapse"
                    style="margin-top: 6px">
                    <i class="icon-white icon-plus-sign"></i>
                </a>
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="filter.checked" id="filter.name" class="parentCheckbox allFilterCheckbox"/>
                <label
                    style="display: inline;" for="filter.name">
                    {{filter.label}}
                </label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `filter.checked` is set to a string (`"true"`) and not a boolean.

For `ngModel` to work with a checkbox, you need to use a boolean.  That's why you had to say `ng-checked="filter.checked"` in the sub items in your fiddle for those to work.  It is recommended that you either use `ngModel` or `ngChecked`, but not both together.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. I actually have this array being populated by a call to the server. Thanks.